# How to hide a tab in tablayout

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout

I have a `tablayout` with about `9 tabs`. I add tabs like this.

```
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
TextView tab = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tab.setText("TEXT");
tab.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_special_offer, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(8).setCustomView(tab);
```

we want to `disable` some of it. I think hiding it would be more efficient than putting validations in every way to access a tab. but I don't know how to hide them.

here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.flipboard.bottomsheet.BottomSheetLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomsheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/colorFragmentBG">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>
     </RelativeLayout>
</com.flipboard.bottomsheet.BottomSheetLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to get tabhost:

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

And after that use this expression, choosing the tab you want:

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(8).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

for example '8' would be 9th tab.

----------- EDIT -----------

I am assuming your xml is something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
   android:id="@android:id/tabhost" …/>
   <LinearLayout …>
         <TabWidget
               android:id="@android:id/tabs" …/>
         <FrameLayout
               android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" …>
   </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: is tabhost a built-in component of i need to add it in my layout